# How to insert a value from a PHP form to another SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a PHP form with radio buttons so on submit it will produce a roomCode based on the one I have selected. I am struggling to show the other SQL statement once the submit button has been pressed.

PHP:

```
<?php 
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    {
        if(isset($_POST['proj_check']))
            $proj_check = $_POST['proj_check'];
        else
            $proj_check = "N";

        $numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
        $roomtype= $_POST['roomtype'];
        $selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` 
            WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption' 
            AND `Park` LIKE '$selectOption%'
            AND `dataProjector` LIKE '$proj_check%' 
            AND `Whiteboard` LIKE '$white_check%' 
            AND `OHP` LIKE '$ohp_check%' 
            AND `WheelchairAccess` LIKE '$wheel_check%' 
            AND `lectureCapture` LIKE '$cap_check%' 
            AND `Style` LIKE '$roomtype%'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
                echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
        echo "<table>"; 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                           
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td></tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='radio' name='radioSelect' value= '". $row['roomCode']."'></td>";
                }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='ttroom' id='ttroom' name='ttroom'>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>"; 
        echo "</form>";
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['ttroom'] ) )
    {
            $roomcode = $_POST['ttroom'];
            $try = "SELECT * FROM 'ROOMBOOKING' WHERE 'roomCode' = '$roomcode';";
            $ttres = mysql_query($try);
            if ($ttres == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $try<br />");

                echo "<table>"; 

            while($ttrow = mysql_fetch_array($ttres)){                          
                echo "<tr><td>" . $ttrow['roomCode'] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>"; 
    }               
    mysql_close();              
?>
```

Comment: What output do you get when you press submit?

Comment: Nothing, not even an error?

Comment: May I add, your question is rather confusing. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: So, I currently have radio buttons and the submit button will then produce a result based on the roomCode row selected. Then, I would like to put this roomCode into another statement and echo that result. These queries are from two different tables.

Comment: Start by `var_dump($_POST)`. I suspect that You are checking `$_POST['submit']`, but there is no `<input>` named "submit".

Comment: If you're running queries from TWO different tables, I would suggest you look at join statements.. and also assess what @RomanHocke said... at the beginning of your script you declared a $_POST['submit']... but I don't see an input for that particular declaration.

Comment: So you basically want to select a radio button and then press submit and on the following page, you want it to echo the option you selected?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something that I **assume** you're trying to do:

**Website:**

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

What the above link does is basically creates a form, sets some form validation and asks the user to complete the form. Once the user has completed the form and submitted the form, it echoes the results entered. Now I'm assuming that is what you're looking for. And if you're worried about communicating with the database, you could basically place all the form field names into individual variables and then run an insert query at the same time. So you can echo based on your insert query. Now I noticed in your code, you used a table... forms, tables.. the concept is the same. Give it a go, let me know what you get!

Hope this helps,

Sohail